# Will running a guitar through a bass amp and then through a guitar amp hurt either amplifier?

Tags: electric-guitar, amplifiers

I play guitar and recently bought a bass and bass amp. I will sometimes run my electric guitar through the bass amp and into my guitar amp like an extension speaker. I was wondering if this could damage either the guitar amp or the bass amp?
Bass Amp: Epiphone Electar 15B
Guitar Amp: Epiphone Electar 10
Guitar: Epiphone Les Paul Special II

Comment: Without knowing more details - what amps, what outputs, what inputs you want to use, this can't be answered safely.

Comment: See the answers to [this question of mine](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/48961/incorporate-guitar-amp-in-my-bass-rig). I think a crossover is probably the best suggestion.

Comment: ambiguous question. How are you actually connecting things? Speaker output of bass amp to guitar input of guitar amp (yuk)? connecting both speakers to the power output of the bass amp? if so, series or parallel?

Answer (score 1):

I general, the main difference between the bass and guitar amp is that the speaker on the bass amp is more durable. Often bass amps wont have good high frequencies, but it wont harm a bass amp to plug a guitar into it. Usually the amplifier circuits are pretty similar and its usually the speaker that is the main issue.

Because guitar amps aren’t designed to handle the high output and low frequencies of the bass guitar, the speaker of the guitar amp could be damaged when plugging in a Bass guitar. It should be fine if you only put the volume low.

It will probably be fine to use the guitar amp as an extension speaker to the bass amp if you are playing the guitar, but playing the bass through the guitar amp speaker like that probably wouldn’t be a good idea.

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to use the electric guitar with a bass amp (Example: Josh Homme)

I use my bass guitar at home with a guitar amp, but if I load it, the speaker may be damaged.  Be careful, too.

Comment: This is even more vague than the question.

Comment: This post doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange.  I don't mean to be critical, but there is something you should know that will allow you to get more benefit from this Exchange.  This is not a forum where folks casually converse as if talking to someone about music at a party.  It is a resource that people can use to learn about music from the members of the SE community.  It also serves as a resource for people in general who turn to search engines for answers.  Good answers will show on Google Search.  Answer as if many others with a similar question will read in the future so your contributions will help all.